# NOTEPAD++ correcting image file path using FIND & REPLACE feature

Tags: notepad++, find-replace

I have thousands of html files that i need to edit to correct the image file path.  I am wondering if I can add the folder name in the path using NOTEPAD++ FIND AND REPLACE feature. Anyone knows if this can be done using NOTEPAD++?

If I have this tag below and I like to add a folder name before the image filename, I like to know if we can automate notepad++ to add the folder name "images" using FIND AND REPLACE.

**FROM**

```
<img src="a002p.jpg">
```

**RESULT I LIKE TO ACHIEVE**

```
<img src="images/a002p.jpg">
```

I tried the steps as shown in the screenshot and that didn't solve the problem.

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/636xf.jpg
```

[image: notepad++ find and replace feature]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `"(?=\w+\.jpg")`
- Replace with: `"images/`
- **UNCHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
"           # a double quote
(?=         # positive lookahead, make sure (but don't capture) we have after:
    \w+         # 1 or more word character (you may use .+? if you have other character than word char)
    \.jpg       # extension (you may use \.(?:jpe?g|png|gif) if you have other extensions)
"           # a double quote
)           # end lookahead
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Didn't expect a quick response but I just tried it and it so...... WORKING. You are such a big help as this solution saves my time. MASSIVE MASSIVE Thanks!

Comment: And one more thing, what about if I have the following tags below but I only want to target the one with a JPG value?  So excluding the one with the HTM value. 

**CURRENT CODE**
<a href="O2A.jpg">
<a href="h025m.htm">


**RESULT I LIKE TO ACHIEVE**
<a href="images/O2A.jpg">
<a href="h025m.htm">

Comment: To make my follow up question clear, i'm sending my question as screenshot using the URL below. http://technologyservices.io/notepad++4.jpg

Comment: Thank you once again.  It is working now.