# NOTEPAD++ adding folder name using FIND & REPLACE feature

Tags: regex, notepad++, regexp-replace

This is a follow-up question for my previous question that can be found in the url below:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66719731/
```

If I have the following tags below and I want to add a folder name **images/** before the image file, how can i program NOTEPAD++ to add a FOLDER NAME for those A HREF tags with a JPG value. So in short I want to exclude A HREF tags with the HTM value when using the FIND & REPLACE function.

**CURRENT CODE**

```
<a href="O2A.jpg">
<a href="h025m.htm">
```

**RESULT I LIKE TO ACHIEVE**

```
<a href="images/O2A.jpg">
<a href="h025m.htm">
```

Any help you give me would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Regex Pattern

Here is the Regex Pattern using lookahead to find the `<a href="` before a JPG file.

```
\<a href=\"(?=[^\.]*\.jpg")
```

And then, you can replace the `<a href="` with

```
<a href="images/
```

## The following test case passed

```
<a href="O2A.jpg">
<a href="h025m.htm">
<a href="O55C.jpg">
<a href="h127m.html">
<img src="images/h001p.jpg" width="175" height="217" alt="h001p">
```

**Output**

```
<a href="images/O2A.jpg">
<a href="h025m.htm">
<a href="images/O55C.jpg">
<a href="h127m.html">
<img src="images/h001p.jpg" width="175" height="217" alt="h001p">
```

Comment: It is partly working but its affecting other tag.  I just want the regex pattern to target the <a href> tag alone. Unfortunately, its doing something like this in the other tag, example:   <td rowspan="images/12"><img src="images/images/h001p.jpg" width="175" height="217" alt="h001p"></td>

Comment: @Irumi Ok, I have updated my answer. Please let me know if it works!

Comment: I really appreciate the time you spent in helping me with this and I noted the new steps you provided as that is something that I can surely use in the future but prior to updating your answer, I actually corrected the other issues that I described in my first response to you.  I simply use the traditional FIND & REPLACE feature without using any REGEX PATTERN. See this url:  http://technologyservices.io/notepad++5.jpg